# Polynomial Multiplication Divide and Conquer Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, polynomials, divide-and-conquer

> I am trying to create a python code for Divide and Conquer for polynomial multiplication using sub-problem technique. Such that it can be later on expanded to multiple sub-problems, like 2 sub-problem, 6 sub-problem or 8 sub-problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not able to understand where to start from, the simple method I do know but I am not sure how to start with this specific method.